# Which version of pylint can be used with python 2.6.6?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, python-2.6, pylint

I have to use **Python 2.6.6** on linux host and I am trying to use **pylint**. Available versions I have are **1.9.5** or **1.6.4**. 
But when I am trying to use them I am getting following errors?

```
% pylint --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "../pylint/1.9.5/ppylint/bin/pylint", line 5, in <module>
from pylint import run_pylint
File "../pylint/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
from .__pkginfo__ import version as __version__
File "../pylint/__pkginfo__.py", line 25, in <module>
from pkg_resources import parse_version
File "../pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 959, in <module>
class Environment:
File "../pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 963, in Environment
self, search_path=None, platform=get_supported_platform(),
File "../pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 190, in get_supported_platform
plat = get_build_platform()
File "../pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 393, in get_build_platform
from sysconfig import get_platform
ImportError: No module named sysconfig
```

- Can this be fixed somehow without removing something from the installation? e.g. I am not allowed to remove files from ../pkg_resources/
- Is there are some other pylint version compatible with python 2.6.6 that would have the option **--msg-template** which is mandatory for pydev plugin for eclipse?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

That is a very old version of Python that is not supported anymore. Doesn't mean it's impossible though.

It reached end of life around [October 2013](https://grokbase.com/t/python/python-dev/13939886an/python-2-6-to-end-support-with-2-6-9-in-october-2013), so a version of *pylint* released around that time or earlier might be OK for you.

- [pylint 1.0.0](https://pypi.org/project/pylint/1.0.0/) released 2013-08-06, introduced the `--msg-template` otion as per [changelog for pylint 1.0.0](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/whatsnew/changelog.html#what-s-new-in-pylint-1-0-0)
- [pylint 1.1.0](https://pypi.org/project/pylint/1.1.0/) released 2013-12-22

Are you using a virtual environment? That would probably make things a bit easier.

- [virtualenv 15.2.0](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/15.2.0/) should be the last version supported

Comment: Thank you @Sinoroc I will try it, I need to check it those versions of pylint has the option '--msg-template'

Comment: The `--msg-template` option was introduced in pylint 1.0.0, see the [changelog for pylint 1.0.0](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/whatsnew/changelog.html#what-s-new-in-pylint-1-0-0)